# Truly Random Values

Tags: keys, one-time-pad

I am trying to build a one-time pad encryption software and I am thinking about simply using `/dev/random` to generate keys.

My question is: Is it `truly random` or `pseudo-random`? Or would it be better to use data from (for example) a website like `random.org`?